# Safe to uninstall Mosaico extension?

Tags: wordpress, extension, mosaico

Last April, I installed the Mosaico extension on CiviCRM / WordPress. Although the install seemed to be successful (Mosaico shows up in the list of extensions as enabled), I get a message "ImageMagick is not installed" when I go to the CiviCRM dashboard.

I'd like to now to uninstall Mosaico. I found these instructions:

In order to uninstall extension, you need to disable it first - once disabled, you will see the "Uninstall" link. Click it in order to completely remove the extension from your system, including permanent deletion all of its custom data. To preserve the data, take a backup before uninstalling. (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/)

As far as I know I have never really used Mosaico.  I do have a backup of the database and all files, but I'm just wondering before I proceed if uninstalling could cause any problems, or if there's anything else I might need to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mosaico doesn't create any custom data in CiviCRM, so it is safe to Uninstall the extension. However, any template created in Mosaico will be lost.

To uninstall the extension you will need to disable it.